# I want to fetch my videos from google drive and show in my react app

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to fetch my videos from google drive and show in my react app but after some request the error code 403 and when I open that URL in chrome I got this massage :

## Google

> Sorry...
> We're sorry...
> ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
> See Google Help for more information.
> Google Home****

I am fetching my video from drive using this Drive API and a key which I generated in google console
This is the URL :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/< FILE ID >?alt=media&key=< KEY >"
```

Comment: Is the file set to public?

Comment: Have you requested this file multiple which triggered the google's spam detection?

Comment: No, I have multiple videos on the drive and I open each file one time

Comment: Can you please share the payload used when it comes to request the file in your react app? Also, are you using axios as the client? HTTP 403 might be because you are not using the correct scope.